# Why does android:singleLine="true" change width and height?

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

Iv'e already set the EditText width and height, I want the user will press next on keyboard and he will move to the next EditText, but when I set android:singleLine="true", the width and height are changing.
Here is my code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/user2"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@color/Alpha_White"
        android:ems="10"
        android:height="37dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_username"
        android:maxLength="22"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:textColorHint="#DDAAAAAA"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:width="230dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />
```

Comment: Try to use `android:maxLines="1"` instead...

Comment: Not working (The next key), if i add "singleline", the key appears but the width and height are changing, if I set maxlines="1", the size is okay but the button doesn't appear.

Comment: What is happening to width and height?

Comment: @joao2fast4u the EditText is shrinking, like ignoring the width and height properties

Comment: Why do you have android:width and android:layout_width? Can't you use just one of them?

Comment: ohhh, it's the problem? so which of them should I use so it will work?

Comment: android:layout_width and android:layout_height will be enough.

Comment: @joao2fast4u and should I use the maxlines or singleline?

Comment: android:singleline="true" will do if you just want one line.

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer so you can accept it/up-vote it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to have android:layout_width and android:width in the same `View`. `android:width` value will be ignored. Use only `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` and put your fixed values there, like this:

```
android:layout_width="230dp"
android:layout_height="37dp"
```

Use `android:singleLine="true"` to allow your `EditText` to have only one line.